# Can I clip raster maps by vector boundaries on fly while serving them via geoserver?

Tags: raster, geoserver, clip

I have a lot of georeferenced raster topographic map sheets which contain not only map itself, but some sketch elements like legends, stamps outside the map frame. I want to make seamless coverage from these rasters, which will be served by geoserver WMS. But I don't want to make two copies of these rasters originals and clipped by map frame that produce seamless coverage.So is there any way in geoserver to clip these rasters by map frame boundary on fly like in ArcGIS mosaic catalog? 
  Thanks

Comment: I think the basic answer is yes, either with wps directly, or in the sld, kinda like what they're doing here - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102656/how-to-crop-coverage-with-wps-chain-in-sld